# An honest review of my workout

Tags: workout-routines, beginners

So im a 14 year old beginner wanting a body like bruce lee, Muscles but not too big like the bodybuilders, and six pack and stuff. And i did some research of workouts that could maybe help me, and i have made this full-body workout.

Age 14
Weight i think 50 kg
Height i think 170 cm

Exercise one:  Push-up

Exercise two: Goblet Squat

Exercise three: Russian Twist

Exercise four: Hollow Hold

Exercise five: Leg raises

Exercise six: Clean and Press

Exercise seven: 5 Second alternating Single Leg Wall Sit

Exercise eight: Rear Delt Flyes

Exercise nine: Dumbbell Curls

Exercise ten: Tricep Kickbacks

Comment: Fun fact, you can't get big muscles on accident.

Answer (score 3):

I personally think following a pre-defined protocol is the best. They think of the basic movement of humans (push, pull, etc) and devise a method based on that. When we do our own programs we usually tend to forget some important stuff.

That is why I recommend a book on bodyweight workouts. I believe at this age, bodyweight workout would do just fine. **You are your own gym** is a very good bodyweight book by Mark Lauren.